# Fixed toolbars not working correctly when displayed in a single HTML

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

We are using jQuery mobile 1.0a2 [fixed toolbars](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html) for our app. However we want to load all the HTML layout in a single attempt and from there load only the data through Ajax calls. We managed to make the bars work but the bottom one behaves quirky and sometimes ends up floating at the middle of the screen.

I understand that the bars are designed to work using multiple HTMLs.

Do anyone knows a way to fix/force this?

Comment: We already tried 1.0a3 but it caused more problems than it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to do the same exact thing and got this same behavior you were talking about. I looked into it, and there were actually a lot of known problems with the fixed toolbars in the Alpha 2 release. In Alpha 3 they drastically improved the fixed toolbars, and it solved all the issues I had.

I realize you said you had problems moving up to the Alpha 3 release, and I'm guessing it introduced bugs in other parts of your code which is why you didn't end up using it. However, if you're serious about using these fixed toolbars, I feel like you should really try to fight through those newly introduced errors and begin using JQM Alpha 3. Solving your toolbar issues while using Alpha 2 will end up being extremely tough, and you probably won't get much help from the JQM experts since that code is now old...

Comment: I confirm - alpha2 should not be used anuymore. Also - migrating is easy compared to alpha1->alpha2

Comment: Yeah that's exactly why we chickened out on Alpha 3, we felt like it was not worth the trouble, until the app went live and the user started complaining that the toolbar is extremely annoying to the point that it is our mayor usability problem today, so I´ll guess we need to reconsider Alpha 3 as you suggest.

Comment: Cool. If you have a couple weeks, you might even want to consider holding out for the Alpha 4 release which will be coming out any day now. They're hoping for a beta release by Mid April for the jQuery conference (http://events.jquery.org/2011/sf-bay-area/) which would be awesome.